# What C++ compilers are supporting lambda already?

Tags: c++, lambda

Are there C++ compilers already supporting [C++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x) [lambda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) expressions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Visual Studio 2010 CTP](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/content/content.aspx?ContentID=9790) supports it already.

**Update:** It is now [Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dd582936.aspx)

Comment: you can checkout the gcc lambda branch and experiment. in #geordi at irc.freenode.org there is already a gcc bot running lambda-gcc.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2008/10/28/lambdas-auto-and-static-assert-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-1.aspx

Comment: Microsoft has come a long way since VS 6 when it comes to compatibility and willingness to adopt c++ changes :)

Comment: @Laserallan: Makes sense, really, since VS6 predates ISO C++ ;)

Answer (score 9):

g++ has support since [4.5](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/changes.html).
Status for C++11 support in gcc can be found [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html#lambdas).

Answer (score 5):

G++ supports it in 4.5 if you enable it using -std=gnu++0x.

Answer (score 2):

Intel C++ Compiler does, e.g. according to [TBB](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/documentation.php) Tutorial.