# Handling a C++ libsigc++ signal with a lambda function

Tags: c++, events, signals, libsigc++

I'm working on some C++ code that uses [libsigc++](http://libsigc.sourceforge.net/) for signaling (eventing.)

I'm quite new to C++, and I tend to think in C#.  The equivalent code to what I want in C# would be something like:

```
var names = new List<string>();
thing.Happened += (string name) => names.Add(name);
thing.DoStuff();
```

The [libsigc++ tutorials](http://developer.gnome.org/libsigc++-tutorial/stable/) do a good job of showing how to bind a function or member to a signal, but I don't want to define a new class-level method for such a simple method that should really be privately encapsulated within its client, at least to my thinking.

The libsigc++ API seems to support lambda expressions, but I haven't found any examples showing how to use them.  Can someone help me out?  Remember that I'm a C++ newbie!

Comment: Until the recently accepted C++0x standard, C++ didn't support lambdas.  And C++0X is so recent, I doubt that libsigc++ is written in such a way as to take advantage of the new lambdas

Comment: @aneccodeal, on [this page](http://developer.gnome.org/libsigc++/unstable/namespacesigc.html) there are many references to the term `lambda` in the API.  Are they in fact referring to something else?  It's kind of gibberish to me, really.

Comment: looks like that is a templated struct that they defined not a C++0x lambda function.

Comment: @aneccodeal: C++0x lambdas can be used anywhere function objects can be used.  And function objects have been around for a while.  If you wrote code that accepts function object parameters, you don't need to make any changes to accept lambdas.

Comment: I should say, "If you wrote code that accepts *arbitrary* function object parameters*, in other words, function templates.  If your function only accepts a specific class of function objects, it won't accept a lambda as a replacement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lambdas are just function objects.  So anywhere you can use an arbitrary(i.e. templated) functor, you can use a lambda.

I don't have the library installed, so I can't test this, but looking at [this example](http://developer.gnome.org/libsigc++-tutorial/stable/ch02.html#id2644029), I believe this modification should work:

```
int main()
{
    AlienDetector mydetector;
    auto warn_people = []() {
            cout << "There are aliens in the carpark!" << endl;
    };

    mydetector.signal_detected.connect( sigc::slot<void>(warn_people) );

    mydetector.run();

    return 0;
}
```

**P.S.**

I wasn't entirely confident in this answer since I couldn't test it.  I found that constructor for the slot class in the documentation, and because I've never encountered a constructor template in a class template, I wasn't sure that the types would all be able to resolve.  So anyway, I wrote a test using only the standard library that does something like what that constructor does, and it works. [Here it is](http://ideone.com/1RLWC)

Comment: sigc::slot<void> seems to be optional. This code works in gtkmm:
`auto quit = []() {
    Gtk::Main::quit();
};

button.signal_clicked().connect(quit);`

Comment: So does button.signal_clicked().connect([this]{ /* method code */ }); which is quite nice.

Answer (score 2):

[C++ 0x supports lambdas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Lambda_functions_and_expressions) and would probably allow you do do something similar to what you do in C#. [See What C++ compilers are supporting lambda already?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349899/what-c-compilers-are-supporting-lambda-already) for C++0x ready compilers.

Comment: I don't mind being -1'd if I was wrong. I'd like to know why the person that -1's me thought I was wrong, though.

Comment: No idea why the fly-by downvote.  I've tipped the scales.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

[This site on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2008/10/28/lambdas-auto-and-static-assert-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-1.aspx) has a very nicely laid out and comprehensive look at the lambda feature as well as the use of the `auto` keyword in C++0x.  It has some really helpful examples, as well as the connection between lambdas and function-objects from earlier versions of C++. Note that you may have to use the `-std=c++0x` or `1std=gnu++0x` flags if you're using g++ version 4.4 or greater in order to get these features to compile correctly.

Comment: Seeing that the OP was new to lambdas, I figured this would be a good opportunity to provide an excellent resource where he/she could learn how lambdas work in C++0x.  So why was this downvoted??

Comment: I don't know. Same thing happened to me. :-/

Comment: No idea why the fly-by downvote.  I've tipped the scales.  Thanks for the info.